# How to Filter a specific value from a Variable Index python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a working code based on `startswith` approach by fining the two specific strings one is `name` which has the value `name: Steve` another Key is `MyProject` that has the changing Vlues like `MyProject: colo` & `MyProject: solo` and so on.. Where i need a specific value from `MyProject` as i needed only colo from `MyProject`..

How to get the required value from `projn = line.split()[1]` from the below code.

```
cmd  = ['somecommand', 'args']
 l_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=False).decode("utf-8")
 for line in l_output.splitlines():
     if line.startswith("name:"):
         data = line.split()[1]
     if line.startswith("MyProject"):
         projn = line.split()[1]
         for out1, out2 in zip(data.splitlines(), projn.splitlines()):
             print(out1.ljust(15), out2)
```

raw values of the command are as follows for example:

```
Name: Steve
MyProject: colo
```

When i ran the code the output will be below:

```
Steve   colo
Kevin   solo
Matin   colo
Gavin   colo
Gustao  solo
```

Required output like:

```
Steve   colo
Matin   colo
Gavin   colo
```

Just an Update: I'm able to fetch it with `if line.endswith("colo"):`  then its gtes the desired output instead of `if line.startswith("MyProject"):`

Though still open with for better code and suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Just used the `if line.endswith("colo"):` statement as the values ending with `colo` string so thats working .........

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# checkProj.py
cmd  = ['somecommand', 'args']
 l_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=False).decode("utf-8")
 for line in l_output.splitlines():
     if line.startswith("name:"):
         data = line.split()[1]
     if line.endswith("colo"):
         projn = line.split()[1]
         for out1, out2 in zip(data.splitlines(), projn.splitlines()):
             print(out1.ljust(15), out2)
```

So, when i run, it gives the desired results..

```
$./checkProj.py
Steve   colo
Matin   colo
Gavin   colo
```